# Issue while upload R data frame to Teradata

Tags: r, upload, teradata

I have been trying to upload R data frame to Teradata. This data frame has 30 million records with 7 variables. Below is the script I used to perform this task.

```
upload_to_new_table(
    conn, 'Temp.Data', Data, batch_size = 100000,
    volatile = FALSE, primary_key = "acct_i", drop_table = FALSE
)
```

Where conn is the Teradata connection object.

The above method shows 1 day to complete the task. I have tried using different batch sizes (100, 1000, 10000) and also without batch size, but no significant reduction in execution time.

Is there any other efficient way to upload R data to Teradata?

Comment: If you are using the Teradata package for R (think that's the name?), it has a fastload API, which is much more suitable for this kind of volume.

Comment: `upload_to_new_table` appears to be a user-defined function. Probably need to post the definition of that function if you need more assistance.